# Screen turning off at random, on any Linux distro

Tags: linux, graphics-card

I've switched an old laptop with the dreaded SiS 771 graphics card to Linux (Debian jessie to be more specific) but while I work or even leave it on idle, the screen suddenly turns off, while the fans are still audible. This forces me to shut it down the hard way and reboot all the way back, losing anything I've been doing until this point.

The turnoff happens at random intervals, ie. it can take from like seconds after the moment the system has booted to 2-3 hours.

FYI I'm working on a native (1280x800) resolution by following the instructions [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=120734#p601888).

PS: I've done some research and found that some distros (like PCLinuxOS) have official drivers for this card. Tried them, no dice.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

*lightspot21*

Comment: Does it happen on a Live CD?

Comment: No, it's installed.

Comment: I didn't ask "is it happening?", but "does it happen?", ie run a Live CD for a while to check: if it happens on a Live CD, then it's probably a hardware / generic driver problem; if not, then it is an installation / configuration problem.

Comment: Oops, misinterpreted. I tried with a live cd (PCLinuxOS) but nothing.

Comment: Edit: By 'nothing' I mean that it didn't fix it, the monitor still shuts off.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I suggest you try another distribution's Live CD. I use Ubuntu because of its support for a wide variety of hardware, and it is based on Debian, so it should be familiar.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try just switching to a different "console", with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F8</kbd>? Those usually switch screen size/graphics modes and could throw a "reset" like command to the monitor.

Sometimes <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> is set to kill or restart the window manager too, it may cause a "reset" also.

PS. Doing a pull-the-plug power off is terrible for most filesystems, if the kernel is still listening (and it almost always is) you can do a ["Magic SysRq"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) reboot/shutdown:

Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd> (keep holding these)
plus one at a time a few seconds apart:  **R E I S U B**

> [Can be remembered with] "Raising Elephants Is So Utterly Boring", "Reboot Even If System Utterly Broken" or simply the word "BUSIER" read backwards, are often used to remember the following Sysrq-keys sequence:

```
  _
unRaw      (take control of keyboard back from X),
 tErminate (send SIGTERM to all processes, allowing them to terminate gracefully),
 kIll      (send SIGKILL to all processes, forcing them to terminate immediately),
  Sync     (flush data to disk),
  Unmount  (remount all filesystems read-only),
reBoot.
  -
```

Instead of B to reboot, O should shutdown too. See this page for more  info too: http://www.howtogeek.com/119127/use-the-magic-sysrq-key-on-linux-to-fix-frozen-x-servers-cleanly-reboot-and-run-other-low-level-commands/

Like check `cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` to see if they're enabled, or `echo “1” > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` to enable them (may need root or `sudo tee`, etc).

---

Or, maybe the monitor/laptop is just failing slowly...

Comment: Thanks for the response, trying now and will report back.

Comment: Tried everything, but it looks like it gets "cut off" from the peripherals, ie. doesn't listen to keyboard or any input. The weird thing is that it never did anything like that under Windows. Logged even once on a tty, just to see if it is a driver issue, but it did the same.

Comment: That sounds like a serious crash, the kernel doesn't even do a "kernel panic" and display any error messages... And you said in a comment that it **does not happen** when running a live ISO/USB/DVD, does the ISO use the exact same kernel/distribution? If a different kernel version or distro runs well all day, you should try that kernel/distro

Comment: I actually said that it **does** happen on a live CD.

Comment: I see, I also thought "nothing" meant "no problem," I'll agree with AFC's suggestion to try some different live distros, if it happens in Ubuntu & Debian, maybe try different "families" like Arch, Gentoo, Red Hat/Fedora. Even try Windows, and if it still happens with every OS then it definitely sounds like failing hardware, I've seen several MB's that would just power off, at first rarely then frequently then they wouldn't even stay on for seconds